# Would it be possible to publish a journal paper about data-visualization website?

Tags: publications, website, publishability

I am graduated with a bachelor’s degree in computer science. I want to know whether is that possible to publish a paper about my final-year project? The final-year project was about a website which contains data visualization of one company’s data. This works had done by help of my supervisor during my bachelor time. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Does it solve a problem or shed new light? This is with respect to existing body of knowledge.  If it's just a paper that says "i've done this", then it's no different to a brochure.

Comment: How did your supervisor answer this question?  (You _did_ ask your supervisor this question, didn't you?)

Comment: @JeffE he said it could be a kind of revision of work paper,no problem to publish it

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus your perspective is logical to me  and i respect it but is it all the publication in the world adding knowledge all the time? in my case lets say i m new to web analytics and i want to review an existing web analytic system to learn, could not be possible for me to study review papers?

Comment: @moh89 You can publish anything as long it is written down.  The only issue is 'where' it is published. For reputable researchers, they only publish when they have something new to say.  Otherwise, it's a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

This would entirely depend on the contribution your website and techniques involved add to the state of the art. Is any element of it new and novel? I.e. something done nowhere else. It may be worthy of a conference paper for example, if he contribution is weaker.

What is your supervisors opinion? Have they hinted at this possibility?

Edit: The company's data may also feature as an issue during publication. Would they be happy for it to be used and if not can you describe your work well enough without it? i.e. if you use a figure in your paper that shows their data, such as a screenshot.

Comment: my supervisor was satisfied to participate in the publication, and he said : there should be no problem for publishing such a paper, but i wondered for continuing my masters degree,could be a case to mark down my resume for such a review work paper?

Comment: I don't think it would harm your​ resume. The explanation of what you was doing is clear, so there would be no gap in your CV. If you to go into academia publications will help.